# FirefoxOS - how to enable swap file on SD card

Tags: linux, firefox-os

Because of small amount of memmory in current FOS (I use production Alcatel One Touch Fire with FOS 1.0.1, btw still waiting for seriously delayed 1.1) it would be good idea to enable swap file on SD card when it all run on Linux in low level.

Then my question is how to enable swap partition on SD card ? I'm able to create Linux swap on my Linux netbook without any problem but now how to enable it on FOS device ???

Comment: Never used firefox os in person, but from what i've heard, it should support `adb shell` just like android do. When you get a shell, just do `swapon` and see what happens.

Answer (score 0):

At this time, I don't think that is an option in Firefox OS. Then you would have to build your own custom build of the OS and flash the phone with it. If that's what you want, the [documentation for Firefox OS](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Mozilla/Firefox_OS) might help you.

Comment: I'm not sure if I fully understand you reply. I don't expect that there is any option in the UI to enable swap partition. I can make swap partition on my SD card, the problem is for first if swap is enabled in linux kernel of my FOS 1.0.1 Alcatel Fire and the second if yes how can I make swapon.
In the documentation page you provided is nothing about flashing AOTF, only ZTE One.

Comment: I didn't mean UI option, but rather option as a developer. Depending on device and market, flashing the phone etc can be controlled, i.e. locked.

I don't know if swap is enabled or if you can make swapon. For this specific question, I'd recommend asking directly to the OS developers [on IRC in the #B2G channel](https://wiki.mozilla.org/IRC).